# Authentication using jwt how to validate http requests

Tags: spring-boot, http, security, authentication, jwt

I am writing web application using spring boot. It is jwt authentication based
I have models User, Teacher, Student, Course. Teacher and Student extends User

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   private String username;
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
   private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
   // Other fields and getters setters
}

@Entity
public class Course {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", nullable = false)
   private Teacher teacher;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "enrolledCourses")
   private Set<Student> students;
   // Other fields and getters setters
}

@Entity
public class Teacher extends User{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
   private Set<Course> courses;
   // Other fields and getters setters
}


@Entity
public class Student extends User{
   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
        name = "course_student",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
   private Set<Course> enrolledCourses;
   // Other fields and getters setters
}
```

And also I have course Api where I implemented post, put, delete, update and
these methods must be available only for those users who are teachers.
My Course Api looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/teachers")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('TEACHER')")
public class TeacherCourseController {

   @GetMapping("/{teacherId}/courses")
   public Set<Course> getCourse(@PathVariable("teacherId") Teacher teacher){
    // code
   }
   @PostMapping("/{teacherId}/courses")
   public Course createCourse(
        @PathVariable("teacherId") Long teacherId,
        @ModelAttribute CourseDto courseDto){
   // code
   }
   @PutMapping("/{teacherId}/courses/{courseId}")
   @JsonView(Views.IdName.class)
   public Course updateCourse(
        @ModelAttribute CourseDto courseDto,
        @PathVariable("courseId") Course courseFromDb){
    // code
   }
   @DeleteMapping("/{teacherId}/courses/{courseId}")
   public void getCourse(@PathVariable("courseId") Course course) throws IOException {
    // code
   }
}
```

My api url gets worse it look like this http://localhost:8080/teachers/{teacherId}/courses/{courseId}
How can I check whether teacher requests his courses not other teachers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not make courses a top-level resource? You would have a path like `/courses{courseId}`. In the handler method, you check the `sub` claim from the JWT token that authenticated the request. If the claim does not match the teacher id of the teacher giving the course, you return a `403 Forbidden` response.

Even though courses are taught by a teacher, it makes sense they should be their own top-level resource because students can likely list them and sign up for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a success spring security configuration:

- web login
- token generation
- pass token as header in each api invocation

You must to have access to the spring security context in order to get the email of user who is invoking your rest endpoint:

- https://mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/
- http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-security-get-authenticated-principal-details/
- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-se

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
```

With the real email (due to your web login before api invocation) and a query to your database, you can ensure that the teacher only requests its courses and show and error if not: You don't have access to this course.

## Advice : List only my courses

If is and endpoint just for **simple** teachers, Do not set the **teacherId** as a parameter:

```
http://localhost:8080/teacher/courses/{courseId}
```

This teacherId is not required since, you could obtain it (real email) of teacher using spring security context and search courses using teacher email instead teacherId

## Advice : I am an admin and I need to view the courses of all my teachers

In this case, your endpoint is totally valid:

```
http://localhost:8080/teachers/{teacherId}/courses/{courseId}
```

Comment: I think I should validate request in something called request filter, so that I don't do it in each rest method (get, update, delete, put). How do you think?

Comment: Yeah, but request filer just by /teacher endpoint. By default request filter applies to all endpoints of your api. A more elegant way will be an annotation to your method like preauthorize (https://www.roytuts.com/preauthorize-annotation-haspermission-example-in-spring-security/)  (https://dreamix.eu/blog/java/implementing-custom-authorization-function-for-springs-pre-and-post-annotations) or create a new one!